# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firebase_')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I don't know why I've been having so much trouble with this, it seems like it should be so simple.

This error is being run while trying to set up react-redux-firebase. I've been through tutorial after tutorial, read article after article and even tried to use the rrf migration guide and the [firebase docs](https://react-redux-firebase.com/) and I cannot figure out why this error is being returned.

please forgive my code. it's not pretty at the moment after several attempts to get this tor work.

Here's my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  createFirestoreInstance,
  getFirestore,
  reduxFirestore,
} from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

import firebaseConfig from "./config/firebaseConfig";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";


import "./style/main.scss";

import history from "./history";

import App from "./components/app";
import StartMenu from "./components/startMenu/StartMenu";
import HostMenu from "./components/hostMenu/HostMenu";
import JoinMenu from "./components/joinMenu/JoinMenu";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, firebaseConfig)
  )
);

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: {
    userProfile: "users",
  },
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
};

function main() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <App>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' exact component={StartMenu} />
              <Route path='/host' exact component={HostMenu} />
              <Route path='/join' exact component={JoinMenu} />
            </Switch>
          </App>
        </Router>
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector(".app-wrapper")
  );
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
```

my rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as form } from "redux-form";

import { reducer as firebase } from "react-redux-firebase";

import user from "./userReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form,
  firebase,
  user,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and here's my firebaseConfig.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

try {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch (err) {}

export default firebaseConfig;
```

Here's the full error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firebase_')
    at enhancer.js:30:1
    at redux.js:629:1
    at createStore (redux.js:79:1)
    at Object../src/bootstrap.js (bootstrap.js:18:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:725:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:100:1)
    at Object.1 (app.js:89329:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:725:1)
    at bootstrap:792:1
    at bootstrap:792:1
(anonymous) @ enhancer.js:30
(anonymous) @ redux.js:629
createStore @ redux.js:79
./src/bootstrap.js @ bootstrap.js:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:725
fn @ bootstrap:100
1 @ app.js:89329
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:725
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:792
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:792
```

Thank you all so much for any and all help this community provides. You're the best!

Please let me know if you need any more information and/or files!